# Is there a way to enable word wrapping of text on some simple widgets like QPushButton?

Tags: qt, word-wrap

I'd like to make `QPushButton` word wrap and expand it's height instead of expanding width. How can I do that?

Comment: Yesterday we considered the possibility to display `QLabel` on `QPushButton`, you can use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960548/774651

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved the problem with wordwrap on a button this way:

```
QPushButton *createQPushButtonWithWordWrap(QWidget *parent, const QString &text)
{
   auto btn = new QPushButton(parent);
   auto label = new QLabel(text,btn);
   label->setWordWrap(true);

   auto layout = new QHBoxLayout(btn);
   layout->addWidget(label,0,Qt::AlignCenter);

   return btn;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a QToolButton instead of a QPushButton. QToolButton can use multiline text and QToolButton's size is easier to control than the size of a QPushButton.

Comment: It doesn't seem so obvious how to enable word wrapping on a QToolButton. There is no `QToolButton::setWordWrap` method.

Comment: Simply use \n in button label.

Comment: @deadbird but in that case it quite wouldn't be word wrapping :) That is, not automatic word wrapping ;)

Comment: Note that QToolButton looks different than QPushButton which may confuse users.

Answer (score 6):

A straightforward solution is to insert a line break when writing the text inside the QPushButton just like

```
This button has \n a long text
```

If you are digning in QtDesigner, you can simply right-click the button and then "Insert line break"

Answer (score 3):

For word wrapping in regular QPushButton you can implement proxy style class derived from QProxyStyle.

```
/**
proxy style for text wrapping in pushbutton
*/
class QtPushButtonStyleProxy : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    /**
    Default constructor.
    */
    QtPushButtonStyleProxy()
        : QProxyStyle()
    {
    }

    virtual void drawItemText(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect,
        int flags, const QPalette &pal, bool enabled,
        const QString &text, QPalette::ColorRole textRole) const
    {
        flags |= Qt::TextWordWrap;    
        QProxyStyle::drawItemText(painter, rect, flags, pal, enabled, text, textRole);
    }

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QtPushButtonStyleProxy)
};
```

And later in your own MyQtPushButton:

```
MyQtPushButton::MyQtPushButton()
   : QPushButton()
{
   setStyle(new QtPushButtonStyleProxy());
}
```

See additional information on QProxyStyle class in Qt documentation.

Comment: This will not work. QPushButton's sizeHint will calculate a width without Qt::TextWordWrap. Therefore the button will always be wider than expected. One should also reimplement sizeHint and calculate a button size with word wrap in mind. It will not an easy task though. This method suggested by @Lol4t0 is easier to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960548/774651

Answer (score 1):

You might be doing something wrong. Buttons aren't supposed to hold much text, rather a couple of words describing action to be taken. If you wish to make it multi-line, you'd better consider providing a QLabel with corresponding description.

Anyways, I don't know any [Qt-supported] way to make this. Same problem exists for, say, QHeaderView captions, where it could be even more applicable. Manually, you could always do this by adding `"\n"` chars to your caption strings (which you may automate for sure).

Comment: Well, making it multi-line isn't exactly my request. Still, in the present situation, I agree with it, as the button's supposed to be big and be pressed on a touchscreen. So it shouldn't really look like a common button anyway.

Comment: Consider writing you own button class then? :)

Comment: You can always go to the level of creating custom widgets. The point is to depend on existing components as much as possible.

Comment: @TruthSerum, if it "shouldn't really look like a common button" (per OP) then it's not an existing component. Otherwise I sure agree.