# How can i wordwrap in qpushbutton

Tags: qt, word-wrap, qpushbutton

I want to wordwrap in QPushButton. I tried put label on QPushbutton but that doesn't look good when mouse hover. So it tried paintEvent override method. but this is not work on stylesheet

how can i wordwrap property in QPushButton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to enable word wrapping of text on some simple widgets like QPushButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969086/is-there-a-way-to-enable-word-wrapping-of-text-on-some-simple-widgets-like-qpush)

Comment: yes that post means label on QpushButton but that's not good look well when mouse hover..

Comment: Have you tried the third solution in the possible duplicate – subclassing PushButton?

Comment: yeah.. but it works well..
But, when mouse hover that doesn't look good
hover effect doesn't effect on label but button