# text content does not fit in the button in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on Qt for a simple project. When I am design the text in the box, it is good; but, when I run, it the output does not seem good. You can see the output in the below pictures.

Design mode:
[image: in design mode]

Output mode:
[image: in output mode]

Bigger screen output mode:
[image: in bigger screen and in ouput mode]

Comment: What type is the app? a QWidget app or a QML app? attach a piece of code that is related to problem.

Comment: It is a Qwidget app

Comment: You can use Layouts (from top of Designer) to organize the widget together.

Comment: Did not get what you mean

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to enable word wrapping of text on some simple widgets like QPushButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969086/is-there-a-way-to-enable-word-wrapping-of-text-on-some-simple-widgets-like-qpush)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies I will try your inputs